# Getting multiple columns from TWO tables using a WHERE EXISTS statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

I'm trying to use two name column's in tables and find the similarities/differences using SQL Server. I would like to print a list of students Table 1 that are not present in Table 2, along with all their respective scores and grade. However I am having trouble populating multiple columns with my current script. My script does not populate the test scores but instead prints only NULL values. I've included the table format's and where I am with my both script's so far. Right now, all the score fields are printing NULL values even when they have populated fields in Table2.

TABLE_1_Today's_List

| Name1 |
| --- |
| Kevin |
| James |
| Roger |
| Bob |

TABLE_2_Combined_Scores

| Name2 | Grade | Score_1 | Score_2 | Score_3 | Score_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | 10 | 25 | 34 | 12 | 45 |
| Bob | 9 | 25 | 23 | 65 | 87 |
| Roger | 10 | 43 | 54 | 25 | 98 |
| James | 12 | 43 | 54 | 25 | 98 |

Students in Table 1 that are also in Table 2:

```
SELECT c.Name1, Score_1,Score_2,Score_3,Score_4    
FROM TABLE_1_Today's_List c   
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c2.Name2,Score_1,Score_2,Score_3,Score_4    
FROM TABLE_2_Combined_Scores c2    
WHERE c2.Name2 = c.Name1
and Grade = '10');
```

^This script returns NULL values for all the Score fields but correctly maps the students in both tables. I would like to populate the the Score fields with the results from Table2

Students in Table 1 that are not in Table 2:

```
SELECT c.Name1, Score_1,Score_2,Score_3,Score_4
FROM TABLE_1_Today's_List c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT c2.Name2,Score_1,Score_2,Score_3,Score_4
FROM TABLE_2_Combined_Scores c2
WHERE c2.Name2 = c.Name1
and Grade = '10');
```

^This script returns NULL values for all the Score fields but correctly maps the students in table1 but not table2. I would like to populate the the Score fields with the results from Table2

Ideal Output:

| Name1 | Score_1 | Score_2 | Score_3 | Score_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | 25 | 34 | 12 | 45 |
| Roger | 43 | 54 | 25 | 98 |

Comment: It's because they are in 10th grade. So I am including that logic in both scripts.

Comment: Why do you want to use EXISTS. An outer join will do for you..